# ListPlot in a Table with different colours and labels

Tags: plotting

I am making a Table of ListPlots, in which I superimpose two ListPlots with Show.

I would like to make each nth element of a different colour and with a diffenret label on the legend.

The line in the code is this:

```
plots =  Table[
  Show[ListPlot[cumulativeMaximaOut[[n]][[1]]], 
   ListPlot[cumulativeMaximaOut[[n]][[2]]]], {n, 1, Length[xm]}]
```

Is it possible to make each nth element automatically of a different colour (and label), or do I have to define a string of labels and of colours before hand (of finite length then)?

I tried this:

```
plots =  Table[
  ListPlot[{Labeled[cumulativeMaximaOut[[n]][[1]], "sqrt"], 
    Labeled[cumulativeMaximaOut[[n]][[2]], "log"]}], {n, 1, 
   Length[xm]}]
```

and it says:

> Requested order is too high; order has been reduced to {2}

--

Data for cumulativeMaximaOut is here: http://pastebin.com/cb9i9FeP,

xm = {2,3,4}

Comment: This may have something to do with the internal structure of your data. You need to provide some representative data for your `cumulative...` list, and `xm`.

Comment: Do I just write down what values the arrays have? Is there a better way of providing data here?

Comment: You can use e.g. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to share larger amounts of data: paste the data there and then add a link to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created some synthetic data that is the value of `Sin` from 0 to `2π` with a variable frequency.

```
data = Table[{θ, Sin[n θ]}, {n, 1, 6}, {θ, 0, 2 π, 2 π/500}];
```

`ListPlot` itself can handle the this with multiple colors.

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You need to do something to handle the legends

```
ListPlot[
 data,
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01],
 PlotLegends -> Flatten@Table[
    {"Sin[" ~~ ToString[n] ~~ " x]", 
     "Sin[" ~~ ToString[n + 1] ~~ " x]"},
    {n, 1, Length[data] - 1, 2}
    ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many approaches you can use to create the legends depending upon the character of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure that I understand your final desired formatting. However, here is an attempt at differentiating the two data series present in each component of your data set:

```
ListPlot[#,
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.03], PointSize[0.005]},
   PlotLegends -> {"sqrt", "log"},
   PlotRange -> {{-300, 6800}, {-3, 49}},
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
   ImageSize -> Medium
] & /@ cumulativeMaximaOut
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I guess I was wrong in the code. I actually meant to plot all the three graphs on top of each other, each with a different colour and label. Do you have any idea on how to do that?